# laravel 9 Update, change a field of all rows with the same reference

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I ask if anyone can help me, I import an excel table and create several rows of data with a column with the same reference, I want to update a field with a single input of all the rows with the 'Same' reference, for example I want to change the value of the same column with a single input and update the data to all, or add if it does not exist

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Same</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>255</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>255</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>255</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unclear what you were asking

Comment: I have created an import of an excel sheet, I have a field with a single value and several rows are created, now I would like to modify a value with a single input and modify it in all the rows that have the same data, same is the same value for all lines, I would like to modify it with a single input for example "First" and modify it in all lines with the same data in "Same"